# AdmobError:The constructor AdView(MainActivity.Application, AdSize, String) is undefined

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, admob

I am trying to implement **google admob sdk**, I am geting this error

```
The constructor AdView(MainActivity.Application, AdSize, String) is undefined
```

on this adView = `new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,`

Any help?

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public Application() {
    }
    public void displayAd() {
        if (displayAd == true) {
            // Create the adView
            try {
                if (adView != null) {
                    adView.destroy();
                }
                adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, this.getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id));
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
                layout.addView(adView);
                adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declare adView any where?

Comment: Instead of  AdView(this....) use your activity name like: AdView(MainActivity.this...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,this.getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id));
```

use

```
adView = new AdView(this.getApplicationContext(), AdSize.BANNER,this.getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create your AdView using your Application as input, which cannot do. An AdView is UI component and needs to be constructed within the context of your Activity.

Shift your code to your Activity and pass the Activity instance instead of the Application into the AdView constructor.